# Fabric JS + Gif image animation not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS and i want to load gif image object on canvas.
I already loaded gif image on canvas but gif image animation is not working.

is there any way to render gif image animation with object in canvas ?

I am using below code for render gif image.

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('./assets/images/e8nZC.gif', function(myImg) {

    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:400,height:400});

    canvas.add(img1);

    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
        canvas.renderAll();
        fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
    });
});
```

Comment: is there have any plugin to rendered gif animation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated GIF on Fabric.js Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056636/animated-gif-on-fabric-js-canvas)

Comment: i already did :), but it's fail.

Comment: The [issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/560) is still open, no fix yet. You may use [sprite class](http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite).

Comment: Yes, Also i saw issue. Sorry i can't use sprite class bcz have "choose file" option in front side so.